# What's the cheapest "Digital Reward" in IHG Rewards Club?

Tags: loyalty-programs

I'm registered in the [IHG Rewards Club Accelerate 2016 promotion](http://www.ihg.com/content/us/en/offers/q1accelerate16/registration?promoCode=10797&offerID=QQ0797&cm_mmc=OSMAM-AccelerateMBQ12016-vanity-acceleraterewards) and one of my "challenges" is to redeem a Digital Reward - last one remaining! - to trigger bonus points.

[image: ihg accelerate 2016]

What's the cheapest (in terms of points) Digital Reward that would trigger that bonus point? I assume it would probably be a song download. Alternatively I'm also happy to redeem points for a donation to a charity if that's an eligible redemption.

Comment: They have some ebooks for a few points, but the exact options vary based on your country so I can't link to any one thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the exact options vary by country, and vary over time. However, for most people, what you'll want to do is head to the [IHG Rewards Club Digital Rewards catalogue](https://digitalrewards.ihg.com/), then search for [ebooks](https://digitalrewards.ihg.com/us/ebooks). When you're on there, pick all (no filters) pick to sort by price ascending, then check each first letter in turn. Actually, check the numeric first letters first, they often have the cheapest deals!

Right now, as a UK-based IHG member, in the ebooks section for books starting with the "letter" 0 (zero), I can see some 3 point options. I can confirm, from person experience, that buying one of these is enough to trigger the Accelerate task for a redemption. (Well, 2-3 weeks later, but then this is IHG with their very shonky IT systems...)

[image: IHG UK options]